# A group theoretic formulation for Goldbach's conjecture

Tags: group-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

Consider the action of multiplying by $(n-1) \pmod n$, in the group of units $U(n)$ when $n$ is an even number. This action is a map $f$ defined on $U(n)$ such that for each $x \in U(n), f(x) = (n-1)x \pmod n$.

Remember that $U(n)$ is formed by the predecessors of n that are relatively prime to $n$. The order of the element $n-1 \in U(n)$, when $n$ is even, is always $2$. Therefore, the orbits of that action will always have two elements. Moreover, the elements in these orbits will be additive inverses of the group of integers $\pmod n$.

For instance, in the group of units of multiplication $\pmod {10}$, denoted by $U(10)$, the orbits of the action of multiplying by $9 ~(=10-1)$ are $\{1, 9 \}$ and $\{3, 7 \}$.

Here, we see that there is at least one orbit, $\{3, 7 \}$, formed exclusively by prime numbers.

Therefore, to solve Goldbach's conjecture, all we have to do is explain why there is always at least one orbit formed by prime numbers in the action of $(n-1)$ in $U(n)$, where $n$ is even. Correct?

Comment: That seems like an interesting way to think about the problem.  I don't see anything wrong with your reasoning.

Comment: The order of $n-1$ is always $2$, regardless of the parity of $n$, unless $n=1$ or $2$. Note that $(n-1)^2\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, so the order must divide $2$; and if it is $1$ then $n-1\equiv 1\pmod {n}$, which forces $2$ to be a multiple of $n$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, thanks for the correction!

Comment: @RobertShore, thanks man! Let's try to solve this...

Comment: Take an element x in U(n).

We have:

If (n - 1)x ≡ y (mod n), then

nx - x ≡ y (mod n), and

x ≡ y (mod n), hence 0 ≡ x - x ≡ x + y (mod n),

and x and y are additive inverses in the group Z_n.

The reason why the orbits have length two is:

write t = (n - 1).

If tx ≡ y (mod n), then

ty ≡ t(tx) ≡ t^2(x) ≡ 1x ≡ x (mod n).

t is an involution, having order 2.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: There is zero reasons to think this way to formulate the problem is any easier than the usual formulation. How are you going to argue that there is always an orbit containig two primes? How does the action in any way give you any handle that you did not have before? All you are doing is re-stating that Goldbach's conjecture holds if for any even $n$ you can find a prime $p\lt n$ such that $n-p$ is also prime.